# Enabling a selection element only when two other selections have been made

Tags: jquery, html, django

This is my html:

```
<div>
  <select name="State" class="state">
    <option value="Z">Select a state</option>
  </select>
  <select name="City" class="city">
    <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Building" class="to" disabled="true">
    <option value="Z">Select a Building</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select name="State" class="state">
    <option value="Z">Select a state</option>
  </select>
  <select name="City" class="city">
    <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Building" class="to" disabled="true">
    <option value="Z">Select a Building</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Desired behaviour: A jquery call is made to a django backend to find the possible selection choices for building, only when non-Z value is selected for both state and city. There are multiple (unknown number) of state, city, building selection sets.

Here is what I am contemplating in pseudo code. One difficulty I have is if a .state or .city has change, how do you find the value for the corresponding .city or .state within the same .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on("change", ".state, .city", function(){
    [pseudo]
     if $(this) is not Z AND adjacent (state or city) is not Z
           fetch building options in the backend
    [end pseudo]
    }
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').on('change', '.city, .state', function(e){
    //find the parent div that encapsulates the contextual elements
    var $contextualDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
    //find the elements within that div only
    var $city = $contextualDiv.find('.city');
    var $state = $contextualDiv.find('.state');
    var $building = $contextualDiv.find('.to');

    if ($city.val() !== 'Z' && $state.val() !== 'Z') {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```